# Javascript how to find row number of selected text from pre element

Tags: javascript

I have a solution to get highlight text via javascript from my pre element but how can I get the row number inside that pre element?

**Javascript Snippet**

```
function getSelectedText() {
            selectedText = window.getSelection().toString();
            console.log(selectedText);
        }
```

**HTML Snippet**

```
input type="button" value="Get Selection" onmousedown="getSelectedText()"

class="pre" id="output" name="selectedtext">{{ data }}
```

Comment: What row number?

Comment: It is hard to understand your problem without sufficient data. I'd recommend to add more information.

Comment: where is your row number which you want to get?